# Dealing with non-constant term in Binomial Theorem question

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-theorem

I am wondering this.  Suppose I have a sequence $\{\varepsilon_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ and elements of this sequence are part of a binomial type expression:  For example, my expression is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\varepsilon_k2^{n-k}$$

If I knew, for example that the expresssion was equal to 1, then I would know that $\varepsilon_n=(-1)^n$ because

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\varepsilon_k2^{n-k}=1=1^n=[2+(-1)]^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k2^{n-k}$$

I'm almost sure that the answer is "no" but here it is. Is there any way to simplify an expression like mine as

$$(2+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\varepsilon_k2^{n-k}$$
when the terms in the expansion are not constants such as $x$ raised to powers but corresponding elements indexed appropriately?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. $\varepsilon_k$ needs to depend on $x$, but on the other hand you don't want $\varepsilon_k(x) = x^k$? What kind of answer are you looking for? Note that your previous example of the expression being always $1$ is a particular case by setting $x = -1$: and look, you got exactly $\varepsilon_k = x^k = (-1)^k$!

Comment: There is no any simplification if we do not know anthything about your $\epsilon_n$, if you have a particular sequence $\epsilon_k$ you can work out how you can simplify it if you don't it can not be simplified it's the same thing as asking if we have $1+2+3+\cdots+k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ so what would be $\epsilon_1+\cdots+\epsilon_k$? if you don't know anything about the sequence then you can not simplify it

Comment: @Elaqqad, that was my thought too.  I wasn't sure.  The $\varepsilon_k$ are generated by a complicated binomial summation themselves but as of right now, now closed form and thus, no nice way to write them.  I just thought I'd throw the question out there...you never know if there is something or someone who has a trick up their sleeve.

Comment: @PedroM., currently I have the equation  $$1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-N}\binom{n}{k}\varepsilon_k2^{n-1-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\varepsilon_k2^{n-k}$$.  This generates particular $\varepsilon_n$ when $n\ge N$, where $N\in\mathbb{N}$.  If $n<N, \varepsilon_n=(-1)^n$.

Comment: In your equation above, $N$ is a fixed positive integer and the equation holds for *every* value of $n \in \mathbb{N}$? Or the equation holds for a *specific* $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: For the equation, N is fixed and it holds for every value of $n>N$

Answer (score 0):

> Please note, that the following statement is *not valid*.

If I knew, for example that the expresssion was equal to $1$, then I would know that $\varepsilon_n=(-1)^n$ because
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\varepsilon_k2^{n-k}=1=1^n=[2+(-1)]^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k2^{n-k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> The knowledge that $(-1)^k$ with  $0\leq k \leq n$ in the RHS of (1) give
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k2^{n-k}=1\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   is not sufficient to conclude that
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\varepsilon_k2^{n-k}=1\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>   already implies
>   $\varepsilon_k=(-1)^k$ for all $k$.
>
> In fact the LHS of 3 has $n+1$ free parameter $\varepsilon_k$. So, you could put $\varepsilon_0$ to $\varepsilon_{n-1}$ to whatever you like they should be. Than you can take
>   $$\varepsilon_n=1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\varepsilon_k2^{n-k}$$
>   and the equation (1) is fulfilled.

*Conclusion:* A simplification of the sum (3) in the general case (arbitrary $\varepsilon_k, 0\leq k \leq n-1$) is not achievable.